# localized site - except home, every page gives me a 404

Tags: templating, localization

I have a newly published site, where the localization does not work properly.

https://www.nomadenschaetze.com/de/

When i switch to english, it shows the right englisch homoepage. Now, when i click
another englisch site, for example contact, it does not find the templates.
https://www.nomadenschaetze.com/en/contact
The url is fine, the links have the right domain-urls, but it always goes to the 404.

In my dev- environment though, it is working:
the content and navigation changes to english,
https://dev.nomadenschaetze.com/de/

i am very confused.

my general.php looks like this:

```
 // Production environment settings
    'production' => [
        'siteUrl' => array(
            'nomadenschaetze_de' => 'https://www.nomadenschaetze.com/de/',
            'nomadenschaetze_en' => 'https://www.nomadenschaetze.com/en/',
        ),
        'allowAdminChanges' => true,
        'devMode' => false,
        'baseUrl' => 'https://www.nomadenschaetze.com',
        'aliases' => [
            '@root' => getenv('ROOT'),
            '@nomadenschaetze_url' => 'https://www.nomadenschaetze.com',
        ], 
    ],
```

i have craft 3, in my web folder are a de and en folder. no .htaccess in there in these language folder.

in the web directory i have a .htacces file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

    # language starts with DE
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]

    # else redirect to the English version
    RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]

   # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

in the root directory i had to add a .htaccess file, because i cannot change the root directory on the server to "web".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nomadenschaetze\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess?

Comment: i updated my question. a .htaccess file in the web folder, and one in the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution!

i was not aware, that the document-root HAS to point to the /web folder.
There were old web applications on the server, which prevented
to change the root. So i made the .htaccess file, to redirect to the
/web folder.

But apparently, this is not going to work.
So keep in mind, to point to the right folder.